# automoveToNext() method from developer guide is not working properly

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I'm using the method automoveToNext from developer guide for phone number fields. Even on simulator I'm able to reproduce the issue. After entering the number in the fourth field it circles back to first field or second field and starts overriding the first field, second field so on. Please find the attached screenshot for reference. There is flickering of the entered text as well. Please let me know, if any one have any thing different for Text field control to use for phone number with moveToNextField functionality. Also, focus of the field is not switching appropriately: meaning, cursor will be present more than one field. Please find the code below.

Second question, Can I use same field for phone number with extension combination also. Codenameone don't have phone number control which area code and extension splits. Please let me know

Fields Declaration:

```
TextField num1 = new TextField("", "1234", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
TextField num2 = new TextField("", "1234", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
TextField num3 = new TextField("", "1234", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
TextField num4 = new TextField("", "1234", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
```

Methods:

```
private void automoveToNext1(final TextField current, final TextField next) {
    current.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {
        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
            if (current.getText().length() == 4) {
                Display.getInstance().stopEditing(current);
                String val = current.getText();                    
                current.setText(val.substring(0, 3));
                next.setText(val.substring(4));
                Display.getInstance().editString(next, 3, current.getConstraint(), next.getText());
            }
        }
    });
}    


private void automoveToNext2(final TextField current, final TextField next) {
    current.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {
        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {                
            if (current.getText().length() == 5) {
                Display.getInstance().stopEditing(current);
                String val = current.getText();
                current.setText(val.substring(0, 4)); 
                next.setText(val.substring(5));
                Display.getInstance().editString(next, 4, current.getConstraint(), next.getText());

            }
        }
    });
}

private void automoveToNext3(final TextField current, final TextField num1, final TextField num2, final TextField num3) {
    current.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {
        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
            if (current.getText().length() == 5) {
                current.stopEditing();
                String val = current.getText();
                current.setText(val.substring(0, 4));
                current.setFocus(true);
                if (num1.getText().length() == 3) {
                    num1.stopEditing();
                }
                if (num2.getText().length() == 3) {
                    num2.stopEditing();
                }
                if (num3.getText().length() == 4) {
                    num3.stopEditing();
                }
                if (current.getText().length() == 4) {
                    current.stopEditing();
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Calling the methods like this:

```
        if (num2.getText().isEmpty()) {
            automoveToNext1(num1, num2);
        }
        if (num3.getText().isEmpty()) {
            automoveToNext1(num2, num3);
        }
        if (num4.getText().isEmpty()) {
            automoveToNext2(num3, num4);
            automoveToNext3(num4, num1, num2, num3);
        }
```

Comment: I answered the second question, I'm not sure I follow what you are seeing in the first. A video or screenshots might help clarify that

Answer (score 1):

There is a cn1lib with a control that lets you pick the area: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-activation-ui-builder-pattern.html

There is a similar control in the login page of the [Uber clone app](https://codenameone.teachable.com/p/build-real-world-full-stack-mobile-apps-in-java).

The code of auto move to next seems to be a bit old try this:

```
private void onTypeNext(TextField current, TextField next, int length) {
    current.addDataChangedListener((i, ii) -> {
        if(current.getText().length() == length) {
            current.stopEditing();
            next.startEditingAsync();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This control is to have phone number selection for different countries. But I want to have control for US in the format (111)222-2222-4444. So I'm using Credit card fields and modified to fit the phone number appropriately. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Codenameone have single text field for phone number control which is not usable because landline numbers will have extensions. some scenarios user need flexibility in the control to have area code for state and extension separate in the phone number control to enter.

Comment: Yes our control is designed for SMS verification not for your use case. Your approach should be the way to go and you can get inspiration from what we did in that control. The screenshot you are seeing looks like a bug in the text editing. Was this on an Android device or the simulator? Is this something you can reproduce consistently with a test case/instructions? If so please file an issue on that [here](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new) it's a constant whack-a-mole on text editing nuances with the various platforms

Comment: Sure Shai. Thnak You. Screenshot refers Textfield overlapping text on Simulator. Same thing happens on IOS and android as well.

Comment: I feel cn1 should have inbuilt control for this functionality. Do you think this can happen anytime soon. Thanks.

Comment: Looking again at the code it seems automove next is a bit out of date, I edited my answer with a newer version. Where did you get that from exactly? What would you expect us to have? A number control or a masking control? The former is a bit user specific. The latter is a bit hard to generalize correctly as input validation on mobile is nothing like input validation on desktop where you can just detect keyboard input. We thought about this a lot when doing the validation framework but it's hard to generalize effectively

Comment: I'm looking for masking control. In US, that is the standard format every one follows. So either new phone control  or at least masking will help. This is the link I used the code from : https://www.codenameone.com/blog/validation-regex-masking.html. Same code exists in the latest Developer Guide as well. Thanks

Comment: I don't think a phone UI control makes sense in the core but it should be pretty easy to add a cn1lib for common controls like we did with the SMS callback code. We'll try to fix the sample in the developer guide and note the outdated nature of the code in the masking post

Comment: Modified still doesn't work properly.  Current field value will gets copied over to next fireld automatically and I have applied fieldname.maxSize(10) and fieldname.maxSize(4) still field is editable and will be able to enter more digits. Please see the screenshot for reference.

Comment: Which screenshot? Is the one on the top of this post still happening? On the device or on the simulator? Notice that the device input is very different from the simulator!

Comment: Sorry Shai. I missed the screenshot. Please see the screenshot. This is on iOS device. Text entered in first field gets copied over to second field and still editable from there.

Comment: Is this something you get consistently with this code? Can you please file an issue with a simple test case we can reproduce? Thanks.